# Sylverster's law of inertia

Tags: linear-algebra

Any bilinearform $s$ is Diagonazible and if we tweek the Basis vektor's just a little and order them accordingly,say $\mathcal{B}:=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ we achieve that the transformation matrix takes the following form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
I_k & & 0 \\
& -I_{r-k} & \\
0& & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $r:= \text{rank}(s)$.

It's obvious that the quadratic of $q(v) = s(v,v) = 0$ for all $v \in \text{span}(v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n)$.
Now assume we find another basis $\mathcal{A}:=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ such that it's transformation matrix takes on the same form as above. Also here $q(w)=0$ for all $w \in \text{span}(w_{r+1},\ldots,w_{n})$. Now to my question: I know that $\dim \text{span}(w_{r+1},\ldots,w_{n}) = \dim \text{span}(v_{r+1},\ldots,v_{n})$, since I've proven earlier that the rank is invariant of Basis, but my book says that $\text{span}(w_{r+1},\ldots,w_{n}) = \text{span}(v_{r+1},\ldots,v_{n})$ and I don't see why. A proof would be appreciatet.

Comment: Yes, thank you. @BenGrossmann

Comment: One approach to proving this is to show that $\operatorname{span}(v_{r+1},\dots,v_n)$ is equal to the subspace 
$$
\{x \in \Bbb R^n : q(x,y) = 0 \text{ for all } y \in \Bbb R^n\}.
$$
because this subspace can be defined without reference to the basis used, we must end up with the same space regardless of which basis was used to diagonalize the bilinear form.